# Accessing someone else's ICloud?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way of accessing my husband's iCloud to possibly retrieve deleted messages.  I know ICloud ID and good idea of password.  Question is if I log in from a different device will he be alerted??

Answer (score 1):

Are you suspecting a mistress ? ^^

And yes, your 'husband' will be alerted by this mail :

> Your Apple ID was used to sign in to iCloud on - device -

**Accessing to a "someone else's iCloud" without permission is illegal.**